# Create subdirectory in Sql Server FileTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, filetable

I have a simple script that creates subdirectory in FileTable:

```
INSERT INTO MyFiles (name, is_directory)    
VALUES ('SomeFolder', 1, 0)
```

It works corrrect and if I run it SqlServer creates subdirectory 'SomeFolder'. 
But if I try to create nested subfolder I face with an error:

```
INSERT INTO MyFiles (name, is_directory)    
VALUES ('FirstLevel\SecondLevel', 1)
```

Error message is: `An invalid filename, 'FirstLevel\SecondLevel', caused a FileTable check constraint error. Use a valid Windows filename`.

As I know I must add parent_path_locator column for parent folder, for instance:

```
INSERT INTO MyFiles (name, is_directory, parent_path_locator)   
VALUES ('SecondLevel', 1, pathLocatorForFirstLevel)
```

But I have not `pathLocatorForFirstLevel` cause `FirstLevel` is not created yet. Maybe anyone know how to create subfolder with arbitrary name?

Comment: *nix os's use '/' as a folder name separator. Windows uses '\'. No idea if what you're trying will work, though.

Comment: @simonatrcl I tried to use both variants. It doesn't work unfortunatelly

Comment: Do you need to use FileTableRootPath() along with GetPathLocator() to generate a proper path?  See for an example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73854/how-to-get-sql-server-filetable-path-locator-for-subfolder-by-its-literal-path

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I needed to solve this too and figured I'd post what I finally figured out. The article at [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6048/sql-server-hierarchyid-data-type-overview-and-examples/) got me going in the right direction.

To insert the first level folder called 'folder1' you'd use something like;

```
INSERT myFileTable ([name], path_locator, is_directory)
VALUES('folder1', '/1/', 1)
```

Then for the second level folder named 'folder2' you'd use;

```
INSERT myFileTable ([name], path_locator, is_directory)
VALUES('folder2', '/1/8/', 1)
```

Then to add a file named 'filename1.jpg' to the second level folder you'd use;

```
INSERT myFileTable ([name], path_locator, file_stream)
VALUES('filename1.jpg', '/1/8/44/', @varbinaryData)
```

The values between the slashes in the path_locator need to be numeric so for my case the paths where already integers so I could just use them. For the file I used CHECKSUM('filename1') to turn that into an int and then cast the int values into varchar and concatenated them all together with the slashes. There are some limitations on the numeric parts, go to [for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score -1):

Using some C# code, the folder can be quickly verified and created if it does not exist.

```
using System.IO;            
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(FileServerPath + @"\" + 'FirstLevel\SecondLevel');
```